# How to set custom context to a Celery Task

Tags: python, django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

I've been working with Celery and Django, and everything is going fine, except when I need to retry a failed task.

It raises the exception and never sends the task again (according to what I see in Celery Flower)

Here is how I declared the task

```
# Enqueue this on "my_cool_queue", retry it no more than ten times and delay the retries by 10 seconds
@celery.task(queue='my_cool_queue', max_retries=10, default_retry_delay=10)
def task(arg1, arg2):
    try:
    # do some things with arg2 and arg2
    except suds.WebFault, fault:
        task.retry(exc=fault, args=[arg1, arg2], queue='my_cool_queue')
```

I'm running celery with this command

```
python manage.py celeryd --concurrency=2 -B -Q my_cool_queue,cron -l INFO
```

I have two queues, my_cool_queue where I put all my user-generated tasks and cron, where I have all my scheduled tasks.

What am I missing??

**EDIT:**

Debugging a little bit celery's retry method, I've found that it isn't retrying the task
because it receives the default context which has the "called_directly" parameter in True

So, the first few lines on this method are the following:

```
 # Not in worker or emulated by (apply/always_eager),
 # so just raise the original exception.
 if request.called_directly:
     maybe_reraise()  # raise orig stack if PyErr_Occurred
     raise exc or RetryTaskError('Task can be retried', None)
```

The question might be "how can I change this in an elegant way", so I don't have to
write directly on the task:

```
task.request.called_directly = False
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: are you listening on the right exception ?

Comment: I tried with Exception, fault, and got the same behavior. :-(

Comment: It seems that you have hit a bug where the name 'task' is no longer the currently running task.  What broker do you use, and on which platform?  The development version (to be 3.1) makes sure that this never happens again by introducing `@app.task(bind=True) def task(self): self.retry(...)`

Comment: lol, thank you very much @asksol i'm using celery 3.0.23, rabbitmq and everything on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be set at the first place. Your problem is not how to change it but how to call a task without this attribute at the first place.

Do you `.delay` your task? Are you not using eager mode for sure?

Which version of celery are you running?

Comment: Yes, i'm calling my tasks with apply_async(), using Celery 3.0.23 and using the default configuration, I think "aways eager" is false by default